# Laravel get school users

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a project that will have schools that are already seeded into the database, one user has one school.

**User table has school_id**

I made this relationship:

**User.php**

```
public function school(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\School');
}
```

**School.php**

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'school_id');
}
```

When i do

```
$school = School::where('id', 1)->first();

dd($school);
```

I get every field from the school model but the users aren't there,how do i make that the users appear there too without having to do?

```
dd($school->user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Eloquent feature called [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

So, to eager load all the users, you should do:

`School::with('user')->get();`

Alternatively, if you are willing to automatically load the user without having to specify with(‘user’) every time, you can set the $with property in your School model like this:

`protected $with = [‘user’];`

Answer (score -1):

**Nvm I fixed it by doing this query**

```
        $schools = School::with('user')->get();
```